# Flume to HDFS split a file to lots of files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume, flume-ng

I'm trying to transfer a 700 MB log file from `flume` to `HDFS`.
I have configured the `flume` agent as follows:

```
...
tier1.channels.memory-channel.type = memory
...
tier1.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = memory-channel
tier1.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = hdfs
tier1.sinks.hdfs-sink.path = hdfs://***
tier1.sinks.hdfs-sink.fileType = DataStream
tier1.sinks.hdfs-sink.rollSize = 0
```

The source is a `spooldir`, channel is `memory` and sink is `hdfs`.

I have also tried to send a 1MB file, and flume split it to 1000 files, each one of size of 1KB.
Another thing I have noticed is that the transfer was very slow, 1MB took about 1 minute.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable the rolltimeout too, that's done with the following settings:

```
tier1.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollCount = 0
tier1.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollInterval = 300
```

rollcount prevents roll overs, rollIntervall here is set to 300 seconds, setting that to 0 will disable timeouts. You will have to chosse which mechanism you want for rollovers, otherwise Flume will only close the files upon shutdown.

The default values are the following:

```
hdfs.rollInterval   30  Number of seconds to wait before rolling current file (0 = never roll based on time interval)
hdfs.rollSize   1024    File size to trigger roll, in bytes (0: never roll based on file size)
hdfs.rollCount  10  Number of events written to file before it rolled (0 = never roll based on number of events)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. But now, after this configuration, I cannot transfer more files. Flume says it has been successfully transferred, but I cannot see the file in the hdfs. Any suggestion?

Comment: When flume writes events to HDFS, you will alway see a temporary file in the target directory. You can control the file's naming with various pre- and suffixes. Once the file has been written, you'll also see that hdfs-sink closes it on HDFS. A good start would be to set log4j's log level to debug.